# Restore config databases in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, backup, restore

Is it possible to restore SharePoint config database on a different farm or the same farm using database backup and restore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As a short answer:** **`NO`**

**Database backup and restore** for `SharePoint_Config`is **not** supported on

- The same farm.
- Another farm.

> The only scenario that is supported is restoring the
>   **`SharePoint_Config`** on the **same farm** from the **Farm backup**